# IOS What executes before main()?

Tags: ios

```
objc[1655]: Object 0x2314e0 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no
pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to
debug

objc[1655]: Object 0x2315e0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with
no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to
debug

objc[1655]: Object 0x2316b0 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no
pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to
debug

File:MultiFormatReader.mm Method:+[MultiFormatReader load]  --

objc[1655]: Object 0x2317e0 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with
no pool in place - just leaking -  break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool()
to debug

objc[1655]: Object 0x231800 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no
pool in place - just leaking
- break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug

..++++++++

File:main.mm  Method:main  -- mark..

File:BarcodesAppDelegate.m  Method:-[BarcodesAppDelegate
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]  -
File:BarcodesAppDelegate.m  Method:-[BarcodesAppDelegate
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]  -
```

This is the relative code:

```
+ (void)load {
    MPLog(@" ..++++++++");
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [FormatReader registerFormatReader:[[[self alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [pool drain];
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPLog(@"mark..");
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

This my debug message,I used zxing framework in my APP,But I found before main() method execute, some other code executed already.  Why?  generally speaking, what executes before main()?
What does this program `"  objc[1655]: Object 0x2314e0 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug"` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Move the 2 `MPLog`s below `NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];`?

```
+ (void)load {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    MPLog(@" ..++++++++");
    [FormatReader registerFormatReader:[[[self alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [pool drain];
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    MPLog(@"mark..");
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Comment out the two MPLog lines and see if you still have the problem so we can see if it's that that is causing the problem.

Comment: When first MPLog commented out ,it's normal,just like this:                    File:main.mm  Method:main  -- mark..

Comment: So what I showed in my answer worked? That would be because you need `NSAutoreleasePool` to be called first. Just think of it like the pool of memory assigned to your application, if there is no memory assigned - the string would just leak. If my answer fixed your problem then please press the tick to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set a symbolic breakpoint at `objc_autoreleaseNoPool` to halt execution when this error is encountered. Then you can determine where you need to place your autorelease pools (explicitly).

> > generally speaking, what excutes before main()?

**from +[NSObject load] docs:**

> Invoked whenever a class or category is added to the Objective-C
>   runtime; implement this method to perform class-specific behavior upon
>   loading.
>
> `+ (void)load`
>
> **Discussion** The load message is sent to classes and categories that are both dynamically loaded and statically linked, but only if the newly loaded class or category implements a method that can respond.
>
> The order of initialization is as follows:
>
> - All initializers in any framework you link to.
> - All +load methods in your image.
> - All C++ static initializers and C/C++ `__attribute__(constructor)` functions in your image.
> - All initializers in frameworks that link to you.
>
> In addition:
>
> - A class’s +load method is called after all of its superclasses’ +load methods.
> - A category +load method is called after the class’s own +load method.
> - In a custom implementation of load you can therefore safely message other unrelated classes from the same image, but any load  methods implemented by those classes may not have run yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this same problem. If I put a breakpoint at objc_autoreleaseNoPool, on the main thread, I get the following useless stack trace:
`0  0x332097b8 in objc_autoreleaseNoPool ()

1   0x331fe7b8 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::autoreleaseSlow(objc_object*) ()

2   0x332098de in _ZL22_objc_rootAutorelease2P11objc_object ()

3   0x331fcdb6 in _objc_rootAutorelease ()`

It seems to be hitting the autorelease error before anything in the application has actually started. Could this be the result of some load methods in one of the frameworks I have included in the project?

Comment: Put this here, otherwise the stacktrace is basically unreadable.